# Symfony 2.8 assets 404 in Prod

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I have built my site to live and all my assets are coming back as 404.

The an example link to the assets is 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/assets/css/normalize.css';

I know all my assets live in /web. so when I add /web to the URL and it works,
'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/{web}/assets/css/normalize.css';

I have added a directory index to my root .htaccess which has helped my site load app.php but this does not seem to work for my assets what am I missing?

//
.htaccess
     DirectoryIndex /web/app.php
//

Regards,

Comment: Point your domain to `your_project/web/` folder.

Comment: You should keep your `web` directory as a root directory.

Answer (score 0):

To change the document root via .htaccess

add the following to your .htaccess in your server root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.co.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.co.uk.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

Explained:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

//Enable Rewrites

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.co.uk$ [NC,OR]
```

//Regex expression that matches people who find your domain without the www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.co.uk.co.uk$
```

//Regex expression that matches another way to your domain

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

// from the root file look for the file which you would like to set as your root mine was www/web - and app.php was in there